# How do distribution functions (e.g. Gaussian, Bernoulli, Poisson, etc.) relate to deep learning?

Tags: r, distributions, neural-networks, generalized-linear-model, deep-learning

I know that neural nets use activation functions, but where do distribution functions play into deep neural networks? For example, the `h2o.deeplearning()` function in R has the variable `distribution = c("AUTO", "gaussian", "bernoulli", "multinomial", "poisson", "gamma", "tweedie", "laplace", "huber", "quantile")`.  Where does this apply in deep learning? Also, I came across this quote [from an h2o tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/deeplearning/README.md) that says "H2O Deep Learning supports regression for distributions other than Gaussian such as Poisson, Gamma, Tweedie, Laplace", but again I am confused as to where a distribution function plays into the concept of multilayer perceptrons.

Comment: Currently the question is very intimately related to particular software; as such it seems to be off topic. But you could try making it less software specific, since I think you do have a genuine statistical/machine learning question here.

Comment: IMO, this is enough machine learning content to be on topic here. The question doesn't seem to really be about how to use the R functions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used H2O yet, but a quick look [at the documentation](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/deeplearning/README.md) shows that the `distribution` parameter concerns with regression models (more precisely [generalized linear models](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-training-book/blob/master/hands-on_training/regression.md#2-link-function-whose-inverse-is-used-to-generate-predictions)), e.g.

> ... H2O Deep Learning was run with `distribution=AUTO`, which defaulted
>   to a Gaussian regression problem for a real-valued response. H2O Deep
>   Learning supports regression for distributions other than `Gaussian`
>   such as `Poisson`, `Gamma`, `Tweedie`, `Laplace`.

The same is mentioned in [those slides](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-training-book/blob/master/hands-on_training/regression.md#2-link-function-whose-inverse-is-used-to-generate-predictions). In regression problem you have vector of predicted values $Y$ and a matrix of predictors $\boldsymbol{X}$ and we want to learn about parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. For this, we estimate linear predictor

$$ \eta = \boldsymbol{X\beta} $$

that is used along with appropriate link function $g$ such that

$$ E(Y) = \mu = g^{-1}(\eta) $$

where $\mu$ is mean of some distribution, e.g. normal to be used for linear regression, [Laplace](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior/163413#163413) to more robust version of linear regression, [Bernoulli or binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039) for [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression), with other possibilities being [gamma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67547/when-to-use-gamma-glms), lognormal, [negative binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220545/what-r-parameter-is-used-in-a-negative-binomial-regression/220815#220815), [Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/what-regression-model-is-the-most-appropriate-to-use-with-count-data/204698#204698) and other distributions.

To read more about GLM's you can check the book by [McCullagh and Nelder (1989)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/is-there-a-glm-bible/209536#209536).