# Dealing with "underdispersion" in binomial GLMM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, underdispersion

I try to fit several binomial glmms. My interest is wheather historic and recent samples differ in their climatic conditions.
My data is organized as follows, where `rand.factI` has 62 levels and is nested within `rand.factII` (9 levels). Binary variable `hist_rec` is the target variable; it indicates "historic sample" (=0) or "recent sample" (=1). Variables `temp.5years` and `prec.5years` are "studentized" (scaled). The table has 379 rows (of which 221 are `hist_rec == 1`):

```r
my.data
           rand.factI rand.factII temp.5years  prec.5years   hist_rec
                    3           A   2.7762497 -3.178499380          1
                   27           B   2.0817516 -2.457070449          0
                   27           B   2.0233063 -2.369078844          0
                   35           B   2.0315846 -2.229418671          1
                   41           A   1.5080735 -1.700811294          1
                   93           C   0.4385099  0.162621195          0
                   93           C   0.5894258  0.064214693          0
                   94           C   0.8763280 -0.044050165          1
                   94           C   0.7988891  0.005925186          0
                   94           C   0.5989886  0.104371339          0
                   94           C   0.3690310  0.230485075          1
                  ...         ...         ...          ...        ...
```

I use the packages

```r
library(lme4)
library(pROC)
```

My models look like this:

```r
my.model <- glmer(hist_act ~ temp.5years + 
    (1|rand.factI/rand.factII), data=my.data, 
    family=binomial)
```

Outcomes look ok for precipitation, but I have my doubts with the temperature model. Here is a summary of mean values ± standard error for recent and historic sample, p-value of the model, direction of the indicated effect, residual.deviance/residual.degrees.of.freedom (`dev_resid`) and AUC value.

```r
    variable    mean.rec    r.SE mean.hist    h.SE      p  direction  dev_resid signif        AUC
    temp.5years     0.77 ± 0.051     -0.55 ± 0.056 0.0000          +       0.29    ***  0.9991122
    prec.5years    -0.35 ± 0.089      0.25 ± 0.055 0.0000          -       1.22    ***  0.7806862
```

dev_resid is << 1 for the temperature model, so I assume that there is some relevant underdispersion. At the same time, the AUC is extremely good - somewhat misleading, I suppose.

The QQ-Plot for the temperature data looks like this:

```r
qqnorm(residuals(my.model, type="deviance"), 
    main=names(compare.data[i]))
qqline(residuals(my.model, type="deviance"), 
    col="green")
abline(a=0, b=1, col="red")
```

[image]

I understand that underdispersion is not possible with binary response variables. In [How to handle underdispersion in GLMM (binomial outcome variable)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92156/how-to-handle-underdispersion-in-glmm-binomial-outcome-variable), it says:

> If you have truly binary, ungroupable outcomes (e.g. one of your
> response variables is a continuous predictor that is unique to
> individuals, as would be typical in an observational study), then (1)
> you can't estimate the degree of overdispersion and (2) you can't
> really worry about it (i.e., there may be additional sources of
> variability you don't know about, but they just go to inflate your
> uncertainty, but they don't bias your inference).

However, the low residual.deviance/residual.degrees.of.freedom - ratio in conjunction with the excellent AUC value make me wonder weather this model is erroneous.
My question is: how should I treat the temperature model? `glmer` doesn't allow for quasi-families, so I am kind of stuck here. Does it seem promising to transform the temperature variable? Or is there something else I can do to obtain a valid model?

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92156

Comment: My question was somehow similar, indeed. I edited it, so it should be of new interest.